# AngularJS ng-class with dynamic property name

Tags: angularjs

I have this bit of code for ng-class:

```
ng-class="{ 'active': controller.kit['colour' + ($index + 1)] === colour.hex }"
```

The active class is never applied.
Above this, I have this ng-style:

```
 ng-style="{ 'background-color' : '#' + controller.kit['colour' + ($index + 1)] }"
```

This bit of code works fine.

As a test, I did this:

```
{{ controller.kit['colour' + ($index + 1)] === 'ff0000' }}
```

and if the selected colour is red, then this shows as true.
So that works too.

Here is the full bit of code:

```
<div tabset>
    <div tab ng-repeat="item in teamController.range track by $index">
        <div tab-heading>
            <div class="selected-colour" ng-class="{ 'no-colour-selected': !controller.kit['colour' + ($index + 1)] }" ng-style="{ 'background-color' : '#' + controller.kit['colour' + ($index + 1)] }"></div> {{ controller.kit['colour' + ($index + 1)] }}
        </div>

        {{ controller.kit['colour' + ($index + 1)] === 'ff0000' }}

        <div class="picker colour-picker">
            <ul class="picker-dropdown list-inline">
                <li ng-repeat="colour in teamController.colours" ng-class="{ 'active': controller.kit['colour' + ($index + 1)] === colour.hex }">
                    <a href style="background-color: #{{ colour.hex }};" ng-click="teamController.setColour('colour' + ($parent.$index + 1), colour)"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Is the class never applied on the element or is the style rule of background-color never applied?

Comment: sorry, the class is never applied.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the nested ng-repeat.
I simply changed the ng-class to this:

```
ng-class="{ 'active': controller.kit['colour' + ($parent.$index + 1)] === colour.hex }"
```

and it worked.